# Works in C, but not in C++

Tags: c++, c

The following code compiles in C but not in C++:

```
int *ptr = 25; //why not in C++?
```

Error

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:6:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
  int *ptr = 25;
```

But this compiles in both C and C++:

```
int *ptr = 0;  //compiles in both
```

Why does assigning 0 work fine and other numbers does not work?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Because `0` in a pointer context has a special meaning.

Comment: `0` is a null pointer constant; `25` is not a valid pointer constant.  The first shouldn't compile without warnings in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you can't implicitly convert from `int` to `int*` in C++, however 0 can, due to historical reasons, since it is often used as the value of `NULL`.

If you want to do it in C++, you need to explicitly cast the number to a pointer:

```
int *ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(25);
```

Comment: It is not often used as value of `NULL`, 0 was official value in C++ before `nullptr` arrived. `NULL` is from C.

Comment: okay thanks! I'll check it out. @Tommy Andersen

Comment: @Slava It is common for NULL to be #defined as 0 in C++ implementations - what other value (prior to nullptr) could it have?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I may not express myself clearly - statement that 0 is often used as the value of NULL and that the reason it works in C++ is incorrect. 0 is standard way to express `nullptr` in c++03 and that the reason. And because of that `NULL` is defined that way in C++ not vice versa.

Comment: @Slava in C++ `NULL` is implementation defined, `nullptr` was introduced in C++11, not C++03, in other words 0 is not the official definition of it.

Comment: @TommyAndersen I just used it `nullptr` as a term, not keyword. 0 is valid and standard constant to represent null pointer in c++03.

Comment: @Slava yes 0 is a standard constant for null pointers, this was done to increase C compatibility. I you want to use `nullptr` as a term you might consider not marking it as a code, like: nullptr :)